# Calculate $\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{1-\left(\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\right)^n}{1-\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Calculate $$\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{1-\left(\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\right)^n}{1-\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}}}.$$
I know that the solution is $n$ but I do not know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Show that $\frac{\log(1+x)}{x} \to 1$ as $x \to 0.$
2. Show that $\frac{1-a^n}{1-a} \to n$ as $a \to1$

Hint: $\frac{1-a^n}{1-a}=1+a+a^2+...+a^{n-1}$ for $a \ne 1.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $(a^n-b^n):(a-b)=a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

Using $ \ln(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \mathcal{O}(x^4) $ then
$$ \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} = 1 - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^2}{3} - \mathcal{O}(x^3) $$
and
$$ \left( \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} \right)^n = 1 - \frac{n \, x}{2} + \frac{3 n^2 - n -2}{24} \, x^2 + \mathcal{O}(x^3). $$
Now,
\begin{align}
\frac{1 - \left( \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} \right)^n}{1 - \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} } &= \frac{\frac{n \, x}{2} - \frac{3 n^2 - n -2}{24} \, x^2 + \mathcal{O}(x^3)}{\frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{3} + \mathcal{O}(x^3)} = \frac{n - \frac{3 n^2 - n -2}{12} \, x + \mathcal{O}(x^2)}{1 - \frac{2 \, x}{3} + \mathcal{O}(x^2)} \\
&= n - \frac{3 \, n^2 - 9 \, n -2}{12} \, x + \mathcal{O}(x^2)
\end{align}
Taking the limit $ x \to 0 $ leads to
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \left( \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} \right)^n}{1 - \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} } = n.$$